# CanRDP right set to computer account?

Tags: access-control, active-directory, rdp

I was querying a domain and found an interesting ACL that I haven't seen before.

One of the DomainComputer accounts has a CanRDP right set to another domain computer. How would this work? The domain computer account object using the generated clear-text password could use mstsc.exe to RDP in? Or is there more AD trickery behind the scenes? What would the practical reason be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: CanRDP doesn't sound like a native Active Directory right, to me.  Are you running third party software in AD that extends the functionality?  Something related to Bloodhound 2.0 judging from a quick google search?

Comment: Yeah, I was gathering domain information using that.